# Get current ngrx state without subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I'd like to use Ngrx for OAuth2 services and I need to get current store state without using subscribe.

This is my OAuth function for getting token from localStorage:

```
private oAuth2() {
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oAuthToken'));
    if (token && token.access_token) {
        const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.access_token });
        return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use Redux store instead of localStorage in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I really don't see why you want to get the state without subscribing to it as this is the core concept of Ngrx and you can't get a value from a RxJS Subject unless you subscribe to it:

> The two pillars of @ngrx/store, the store and dispatcher, both extend
>   RxJS Subjects. Subjects are both Observables and Observers, meaning
>   you can subscribe to a Subject, but can also subscribe a Subject to a
>   source. At a high-level Subjects can be thought of as messengers, or
>   proxies.

I hope this explains to you that the answer is NO. You can't get current Ngrx state without subscribing to it!

Comment: Hamed, can you add a link to this question to show where the official quote is from? Readers might find that interesting and useful.